# OpenVPN block users established connection?

Tags: iptables, firewall, openvpn, ufw

following scenario:

I have clients connected to my VPN who are using a specific app that is using UDP Port 54477. However I want to block that connection during the night (ex. from 0-6). So I want to schedule a task that will block their connection. I tried multiple things now:

1. `ufw deny 54477/udp`
   Has no success, connection is still working for them so i tried it manually with:
2. `iptables -I INPUT -p udp  --dport 54477 -j DROP`
   With the same result, clients are still able to listen on that port without issues.

Of course I tried reloading ufw/iptables after applying those changes.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: The firewall rules you've shown won't stop clients listening (a firewall can't do that), but they should be stopping inbound traffic

Comment: Also, if you reloaded `iptables` after making that change you probably threw it out immediately and it won't be there any more. (Don't reload `iptables`)

Comment: I'm also still unsure what the relevance is of openvpn

Comment: Well: Client -> VPN -> Internet. I want to block whatever is incoming on port 54477 UDP for my clients during specific times. But if I try to block it my clients still recieve data through that port.

Comment: "_Client -> VPN -> Internet_". Where does your server fit into this?

Comment: My Server is the OpenVPN. I just found out that the rules I make in iptables to not apply to my VPN clients. Sofor ex. if I deny access to source 1.1.1.1, my clients can still reach it from within the VPN. I want to stop that.

Comment: Please update your question to include this extra detail. Make it easy for people to help you by putting everything on one place

Comment: Oh, and your server _is not_ the VPN. VPN is a connection between machines, "virtual private network". Where does your server fit in?

Answer (score 0):

Try this iptables rule:

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 54477 -m time --timestart 00:00 --timestop 06:00 --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j DROP
```

This rule will drop all traffic destined to UDP port 54477 between 00:00 midnight and 06:00am, every Monday to Friday (excluding Saturday and Sunday)

Comment: This is also not working right away. The issue here is that the clients within the VPN who are already listening through port 54477 are still able to recieve data for some reason.

Comment: this is what the connection looks like: `udp      17 179 src=10.8.0.2 dst=x.x.x.x sport=55422 dport=17001 src=x.x.x.x dst=y.y.y.y sport=17001 dport=55422 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1` y.y.y.y would be the clients real IP in this case

Comment: edit: port is 55422 in thise case due to a different test enviroment

Comment: Okay so I just found out that whatever I change via iptables does not apply to my OpenVPN clients. So the port might be blocked for my server but my clients can still use them.

Comment: You might be right. Try specifying the interface (-i) in the rule like this:
" iptables -I INPUT -i tun0 -p udp -m udp --dport 55422 -m time --timestart 00:00 --timestop 06:00 --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j DROP "

    Where "tun0" is the interface that VPN server is pushing traffic through

Comment: Please update your question @Pequh to include this extra detail. Make it easy for people to help you by putting everything on one place